# How to use function in aar module

Tags: android, aar

First time I build an aar module. I am able to convert my app into an aar module. And I create another new app, and add this aar file into the project, and I am able to make the project compile. My question is how to open up the functions in my aar module and how to call them. I have searched through I can only find C#, but how to do it in java. I am new into this.

I found this [enter link description here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46061/how-to-call-aar-library-methods) but it is for C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are having .aar file. Now you can add .aar file in your android studio project by,

```
File -> New -> New Module -> import .jar/.aar
```

In build.gradle(Module:app) Check if whether your .aar file was added successfully or not.

If successful, you can access your module/aar file methods from your project,
    if not try again.

Yesterday, I faced one problem . I could add .aar file successfully but not able to access classes/methods from .aar file.

I did like below,

I converted .aar file to .jar file (BY renaming .aar file to .zip and then extract),
 copy class.jar file from extracted zip, 
paste it in libs folder of android project, then right click the jar and choose add as library, which worked for me.

Comment: I already have a .aar file. and I create a new project, imported the aar file, and can compile successfully. Problem is how do i call a fragment , let say FragmentA in aar module.